How to change Requested by power automate default site owner name
I am facing an issue in power autoate approval flow 'start and wait for an approval' all time display Requestd by site owner name.but item created another member  in sharepoint.how i fixed this issue and how to display inside Requested by actual requester name and email


You should be able to override it directly in the flow ...


When I am adding Requester as a dynamic content it shows
Created by

So force it to be what you want.

Based on Skin's answers, I tested that you can enter the email addresses of users in your organization without having to select dynamic content.

